# WiX: InstallService conditionally, but install file unconditionally

Tags: file, service, wix, conditional-statements

In Windows Install XML toolset, to install a service, we group `<ServiceInstall>` with a `<File>` in a `<Component>`. To conditionally install the service, we put `<Condition>` under the `<Component>`. However if the condition is false, the file will not be installed too. If I put the `<File>` in an unconditional `<Component>`, then the service has no executable file path and thus installation will fail. If I put the `<File>` in both `<Component>`, duplicate symbols will be found.

The question is, can we install a service conditionally, but install the associated executable file unconditionally?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be really nice if ServiceInstall/@Start attribute can be set to a [Property], so you can still install service without starting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create two components with the different GUIDs' and Ids' and mutually exclusive conditions: one for the file and service, and another for file only. Something like this:

```
<Component Id="SvcComp" Guid="{YOUR-GUID}" SharedDllRefCount="yes">
    <Condition> SOME_CONDITION </Condition>
    <File Id="SvcFile" Name="Service.exe" Source="Service.exe" Vital="yes" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="Svc" Name="Service" DisplayName="Service" Description="Service" Type="ownProcess" Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" Vital="yes" />
    <ServiceControl Id="Svc" Name="Service" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
</Component>

<Component Id="ExeComp" Guid="{YYOUR-GUID}" SharedDllRefCount="yes" >
    <Condition> NOT SOME_CONDITION </Condition>
    <File Id="ExeFile" Name="Service.exe" Source="Service.exe" Vital="yes" />
</Component>
```

You will get a LGHT1076 warning which could be suppressed since the conditions in the components are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I found that what I missed is the File Id. With different Id but same Name, the same file can exist in different `<Component>`.

Comment: That technically works but you'll get ICE validation errors because the two components have the same keypath.  It isn't a clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one service, you can condition out the service actions in the `InstallExecuteSequence` table.

Alternatively, you have to have a CA run during immediate phase, that temporarily removes the entry from the service tables prior to execution during deferred.

I am not a fan of splitting the dll for no reason.

Comment: It's proper application design to factor the code out into multiple classes in multiple assemblies.  You create one assembly that has the server components and you create two assemblies to act as a console host and a service host.  The suggestions you make only create hack MSI's that don't follow best practices.

Answer (score 1):

I've been down this road and it gets complicated faster then one would expect.

I consider having two components (despite their mutually exclusive conditional expressions) with the same keyfile but different ServiceInstall/Control resources a component rule violation.

The way I suggest doing it is move all of your business logic into a seperate DLL component and create two different EXE components.  Set one up as a console/windows app and the other as a service app.   Assocate the components to two different features so that the end user can decide which way he wants to configure the application.   The user can then do a modify operation in add/remove programs and use MSI to change his mind later also.

Answer (score 0):

This is forever old, but people tend to have the same question now.

The way to do this with modern WiX is to surround the service start with conditional constructs, like this:

```
<?if $(var.Configuration) != Debug ?>
    <!--whatever stuff you want to do -->
<?endif?>
```

So for this case, you would install the file outside of the condition because you always want it, and inside the condition, you would add your ServiceInstall and ServiceControl.